# What's the difference between how firefox clicks and chrome clicks?

Tags: javascript, nightmare

I'm having to write a scraper using nightmare. On one the links the website is using a div for the user to navigate away from the page. In order to follow the navigation flow, I would like my nightmare instance to "click" the div. However, nothing happens when I'm on chrome, and obtain the element and call click. Unlike Firefox, where this works fine.

The script

```
let elem = document.getElementByClassName('is-a-div-element')[0];
elem.click()
```

Works fine on firefox, nothing happens on chrome! Any ideas? The site causing issue is using React. Not sure if that helps or not.

The HTML structure looks like this.

```
<div class="nav-element">
    <div class="is-a-div-element">
        <div roll="button">
           <span roll="presentation">Hello World</span>
           <span class="Exit">Exit</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought you were just saying your problem was a nightmare, didn't realise it was a thing xD

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using? [**elem.click()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) is only supported in Chrome 20 and higher.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Above 58

Comment: Do you have a class named 'div'? or is ```ByTagName```

Comment: @PabloCesarCordovaMorales sorry that's a little confusing, the real name isn't div, but the element is a div.

Comment: @Kaiido Sure. Like I said, I'm scraping a website, so it's not my dom structure though. I'm using nightmare to scrape the website.

Comment: But then I still don't get it, sorry... I don't know nightmare (and it's probably where my confusion comes from), but isn't it like an headless browser, ran by the server ? What do FF and chrome have to do with it ?  Also your code is DOM manipulation, while [nightmare way to click](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#examples) seems to be simply `nightmare.goto(URL).click(CSSSelector)`.

Comment: `<div class="is-a-div-element'>` the second quote is the wrong type, and `<div roll="button>` missing the closing quote altogether. I assume you typed this in by hand and it's not a copy-paste from the scraped site's DOM.

Comment: Yes typed by hand to give the structure.

Comment: Edited my question, let me know if that helps or if it was just a typo in the question.

Comment: I have to ask though - how are you using Nightmare in a browser? Nightmare is a nodejs module. Are you scraping the sites and then loading them in the browser or something?

Comment: Nightmare uses chrome

Comment: Nightmare uses Electron (which itself uses Node, V8 and Chromium). What does Firefox have to do with anything? You really need to explain a bit more what you're actually doing.

Comment: Hey @user2734679, did you ever solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how Nightmare relates to this issue since you mention Chrome and Firefox and appear to be using standard browser Javascript, but I'll try answer anyway.

Since you've edited your question with more specific information I'll edit my answer. Now the main issue I can see is that you're using `getElementByClassName`, which isn't a function (missing the `s`).

Do this instead:

```
let elem = document.getElementsByClassName('is-a-div-element')[0];
```

Tested working in Chrome and Firefox:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    let elem = document.getElementsByClassName('is-a-div-element')[0];
    elem.click();
});
```

```html
<div class="nav-element">
    <div class="is-a-div-element" onclick="alert('this was clicked frens');">
        <div roll="button">
           <span roll="presentation">Hello World</span>
           <span class="Exit">Exit</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```